# How to replace deprecated aws ecr get-login --registry-ids

Tags: docker, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to pull one of the Amazon SageMaker Pytorch public images as per this [example](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/pytorch_extending_our_containers/pytorch_extending_our_containers.ipynb). In the example they use a shell script and a Dockerfile to pull-expand-build the container and push it to ECR. Here's the shell script:

```
# The name of our algorithm
algorithm_name=pytorch-extending-our-containers-cifar10-example

cd container

account=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text)

# Get the region defined in the current configuration (default to us-west-2 if none defined)
region=$(aws configure get region)
region=${region:-us-west-2}

fullname="${account}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${algorithm_name}:latest"

# If the repository doesn't exist in ECR, create it.

aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-names "${algorithm_name}" > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "${algorithm_name}" > /dev/null
fi

# Get the login command from ECR and execute it directly
# ( PROBLEM 1 )
$(aws ecr get-login --region ${region} --no-include-email)

# Get the login command from ECR in order to pull down the SageMaker PyTorch image
# ( PROBLEM 2 )
$(aws ecr get-login --registry-ids 520713654638 --region ${region} --no-include-email)

# Build the docker image locally with the image name and then push it to ECR
# with the full name.

docker build  -t ${algorithm_name} . --build-arg REGION=${region}
docker tag ${algorithm_name} ${fullname}

docker push ${fullname}
```

However they use `aws ecr get-login` to get access to ECR. `get-login` is now deprecated in favour of `get-login-password` and running this shell script in awscli 2.0.3. fails. If I understood correctly then the first command (PROBLEM 1) can be replaced with:

```
$(aws ecr get-login-password --region ${region} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${account}.dkr.ecs.${region}.amazonaws.com)
```

However the second command requires the flag `--registry-ids`, which is not recognized by `get-login-password`. How can I replace this command so that I could `docker login` to pull one of the SageMaker images from an external ECR registry?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I replaced (1) with:

```
$(aws ecr get-login-password --region ${region} |docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${account}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com)
```

And (2) with :

```
$(aws ecr get-login-password --region ${region} |docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 763104351884.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com)
```

So the registry-ids replaced the {account}. Also looks like the old ids are off, I switched the 520713654638 into 763104351884 , also switching the Dockerfiles import into:

```
FROM 763104351884.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com/pytorch-training:1.6.0-gpu-py36-cu101-ubuntu16.04
```

After that running the script pulled, built and pushed the docker succesfully and I could proceed.

Comment: thanks! I've struggled with this for almost an hour.

Comment: I keep getting `command not found: jNnV6R3cwZWxseG1kNTY5UitPaG1FbXB5eUtVYTdBWVJvZ2JYZmRFOGsxTGkv` which seems like part of the password is getting broken up.  I'm using Mobaxterm for the terminal
`$(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin https://<registry_id>.dkr.ecr.us-east1.amazonaws.com)`

Comment: command works fine from Git bash